# How to improve accuracy of ARKit for measuring distances between two SCNNodes?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, arkit

Do someone know how to improve measurement in ARKit.

My current ARConfiguration is:

```
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 10
    configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic

    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal , .vertical]
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    configuration.worldAlignment = .gravity
```

I try to calculate the distance between two SCNNodes. Are there any methods to improve this? I try to calculate distances between 2m - 10m. Sometimes the deviation is too high for me (30 cm+).

Is it possible to use the planes to improve the accuracy? Or any other ideas?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

SCNNodes have positions in Vectors see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408026-position)

From the these two properties of your two scenenodes you can compute the distance between them with simple physics. For example your can compute the distance in 2D and the distance in 3d world. An example can be done with these 2 extensions.

```
extension SCNVector3 {
    static func distanceFrom(vector vector1: SCNVector3, toVector vector2: SCNVector3) -> Float {
        let x0 = vector1.x
        let x1 = vector2.x
        let y0 = vector1.y
        let y1 = vector2.y
        let z0 = vector1.z
        let z1 = vector2.z

        return sqrtf(powf(x1-x0, 2) + powf(y1-y0, 2) + powf(z1-z0, 2))
    }
}
```

And then in your main class you can call the static function like that

```
let scnNode1 = SCNNode() //Your test node
let scnNode2 = SCNNode() //Your test node
let distance = SCNVector3.distanceFrom(vector: scnNode1.position, toVector: scnNode2.position)
```

Comment: I already have the method to calculate the distance. The Problem is, that the accuracy isn't high enough

Comment: Have you checked with hand the numbers and you find big difference? The answer to your question is, you have to use the .position Vector3 property. Now if you have big difference it's because of your math. If you want send me the numbers to tell you

Comment: The calculations are right. I checked it and other people checked it too. One big problem is, that the nodes are moving when the distance is higher. They are too far away for ArKit to hold them at the desired position.

Comment: If the distance is too big you have to compute earths radians to get the accurate distance but that happens if we are speaking for km.

Comment: same problem for higher distances. would like to know if you have found solution.

Comment: In that case I had the coordinates of the nodes so I didn't use the SCNNode positions to compute the distance but the longitude and latitude properties of the coordinates.